# java.util.Properties not working

Tags: java, xml, properties

I'm working on a game and I'm using `java.util.Properties` to save the dates.
I want to save this dates in a XML file but I'm having some problems...

This is the method which creates the OutputStream, the XML file and the directory if not exist.

```
public String save(String date, String vname){
    //This is the method which saves the dates

   //There are some controls
    if(!dir.exists()){
        game.log.debug("Saves directory not exists. Creating...", -3);
        if(!dir.mkdirs())
            game.log.debug("Impossible to create directory. The game can't save dates.", -1);
        else game.log.debug("\"C:/MakeGame/saves\" successfully created.", 1);
    }

    if(ostream == null && save == null){
        try {
            if(save == null){
                save = new File(dir.getPath() + game.getName() + " save.xml"); //THIS CREATES THE SAVE FILE IN XML FORMAT
                ostream = new FileOutputStream(save); //THIS CREATE A NEW FILEOUTPUTSTREAM
            }
            if(!save.exists()){
                if(!save.createNewFile()) //NEW XML FILE CREATION
                    game.log.debug("Impossible to make new save file. The game can't save dates.", -1);
                else game.log.debug("\"C:/MakeGame/saves/" + save.getName() + " \" successfully created.", 1);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            game.log.debug("File not found. The game can't save dates.", -1);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Saver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    String saved = "";

    if(save.exists()){
        saved = (String) saves.setProperty(date, vname); //SET THE PROPERTY

        try {
            saves.storeToXML(ostream, "Don't change this save files. This files are used by the games to load the progresses."); //STORES THE DATES IN XML FORMAT.
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            game.log.debug("Impossible to store this saves. The game can't save dates", -1);
        }
    }

    return saved;
}
```

When I load the dates I use another method.

```
public String load(String vname) throws FileNotFoundException{
        if(save == null){
            save = new File(dir.getPath() + game + " save.save");
            istream = new FileInputStream(save);
        }

        if(save.exists()) try {
            saves.load(istream);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            game.log.debug("Error loading dates from save file. The game can't load dates.", -1);
        }
        if(!saves.isEmpty()){
            game.log.debug(saves.getProperty(vname) + " successfully loaded.", 0);
            return saves.getProperty(vname);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But it returns always null. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using your `date` string as the property key in your `save()` method, and then attempting to use `vname` as the key in your `load()` method.

Use `vname` as your key and `date` as your value when you are setting the property like this:

```
saved = (String) saves.setProperty(vname, date); //SET THE PROPERTY
```

Comment: But also the method save() returns always null as the previous value. Why?

Comment: Ok, I've solved. The problem is what you had you said :D